# How do you increase nested update limit in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13163 this PR decreased the nested update limit to 50. I am running into this error:

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Now, *let's **assume** for a moment*, that I don't run into this error, because my code loops itself into infinite state updates and *I really know a higher limit would solve (or at least loosen) my issue*.

Can I increase [`NESTED_UPDATE_LIMIT`](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13163/files/0294115837159c9a9fe5ac48d05cdb0196839ee1#diff-24152ba0b2ac251decb6a12f41bdf116L1547)? If so:

1. How?
2. Can I increase it in a way that it only will affect specific code or will this be global?

---

I've uploaded the code here with an actual description (in the `README.md`) of the implemented problem, but the question remains valid (unless someone sees a different way to solve it): https://github.com/mxmzb/react-marquee

Comment: Can you provide a real life use case where this would be useful

Comment: @codeVerine Yes, here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mayer-ymwic - however, you will need to open the example in a new window I guess. And CodeSandbox will actually say it's a CORS issue, dunno why (copy the code locally and you will see the update depth error). Reload the example, sometimes it works on a wide enough screen. Sometimes it crashes. In the latter case hitting the maximum update treshold.

Comment: If it's happening only sometimes it could indicate a performance issue that should be properly fixed (eg `setState` being called more than necessary or a memory leak. But still, I agree it could be helpful - even just for debugging and software that's not used in production.

In this case I'd have a look into `useLayoutEffect` at Slider.tsx line 48. I can't see any obvious issues there but it's a very large function with a lot of dependencies so would be easy for accidental side effects and loops to happen